# How to call multiple images at a time using ImageView

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android APK, currently using ImageView class API's to read image from XML,

```
ImageView simpleImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x2);
simpleImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

My requirement is to read multiple images from layout-->.XML and display at one shot as like `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` API

I am using "View buildPresoView(Context ctxt, LayoutInflater inflater)" API which returns "View" that represents the content to show on the external display.

Note: I can't use setContentview() because my class not extending from Activity class

How to do with ImageView class API's?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: If you want to display stuff onscreen, extend Activity. Its much easier than hacking your way around Android.

Comment: This requirement is for service, and i am already extending my service from PresentationService class. I am using "View buildPresoView(Context ctxt, LayoutInflater inflater)" API which returns "View" that represents the content to show on the external display.

Comment: So really you want to implement that method? you should add that in the question, it is important. @dasariarun

Comment: And also, this is in a library right? the one at https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation ?

Comment: @Penn yes, it is from the same link you mentioned. Currently one image getting displayed at a time. I want to display multiple images at  one shot. How to read entire layout-->.XML and display on secondary screen. Any pointers how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

According to their demo ([here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation/blob/master/demoService/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/preso/demo/service/SlideshowService.java#L79)), you should `@Override View buildPresoView(Context ctx, LayoutInflater inflater)` with a simple `return(myImageView);`

Like:

```
@Override
protected View buildPresoView(Context ctxt, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    iv=new ImageView(ctxt);
    run();

    return(iv);
}

@Override
    public void run() {
    iv.setImageResource(SLIDES[iteration % SLIDES.length]);
    iteration+=1;

    handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
}
```

Which will display a simple slideshow.